# Android - ListFragment fails on setContentView

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-fragments

Ive been trying to get a listview working within a fragment all day. I dont know why but for some reason the way Im trying to do it, it just never wants to inflate the view. Im using actionbarsherlock if that makes a difference but I dont think so. Heres the class where my layout fails:

```
 public class GraffSearch extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.searchlayout);//<-------------fails here

    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab " + i).setTabListener(this));
    }


    ab.show();
    if (ab.getNavigationMode() != ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) {
        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    }



}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "tabs work "+tab.getPosition()+" user id is "+avrid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SearchListFrag fragment = (SearchListFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.searchfrag);
    //fragment.updateUrl(tab.getPosition(), avrid);

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and heres the layout were I call my fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>


<ListFragment
    android:id="@+id/searchfrag"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="graffit.main.SearchListFrag"
    android:layout_weight="1"></ListFragment>



</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: my searchlistfrag class

```
public class SearchListFrag extends Fragment{

ListView markList;

public SearchListFrag(){};

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    markList = (ListView) inflater
               .inflate(R.id.searchlist, container, false);//<----------Fails Here
     markList.setAdapter(new OrderAdapter(
             MixView.mixContext.getBaseContext(),
             R.layout.searchinnerlistlayout, 
             MixView.dataView.dataHandler.markerList ));


    // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlistlayout, container, false);
    return markList;            

    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {

       super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public void updateUrl(int tab, String avrid) {

    }

    private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Marker> {

        private ArrayList<Marker> marks;

        public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Marker> items) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                this.marks = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.searchinnerlistlayout, null);
                }
              //  Order o = items.get(position);
                if (marks.get(position) != null) {
                        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                        //TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
                        if (title != null) {
                              title.setText("Title: "+marks.get(position).getTitle());                            }
                        //if(description != null){
                        //  description.setText("Description: "+ +marks.get(position).get);
                       // }
                        ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.markimage);
                        icon.setImageBitmap(marks.get(position).getBitmap());
                }

                return v;
        }
}   
}
```

EDIT: my searchlistlayout layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:name="@+id/searchlist"></ListView> //<----this is the id i use that fails

 </LinearLayout>
```

Ive tried a few different setups going back and forth from using a regular fragment and a listfragment with the same result. Heres the logcat.

EDIT: New log cat

```
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{graffit.main/graffit.main.GraffSearch}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.setContentView(FragmentActivity.java:421)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at graffit.main.GraffSearch.onCreate(GraffSearch.java:16)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    ... 11 more
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050068 type #0x12 is not valid
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1912)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:746)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at graffit.main.SearchListFrag.onCreateView(SearchListFrag.java:28)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:845)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1058)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1156)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:660)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
03-18 15:34:45.939: E/AndroidRuntime(20704):    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fragment import in your layout is wrong. Fragments are added to a layout with the `<fragment>` tag. Other than with `Views` you don't name the tag after the fully-qualified class name. The error occurs because Android tries to inflate a `View` with the type 'ListFragment', that doesn't exist.

Try:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/searchfrag"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="graffit.main.SearchListFrag"
    android:layout_weight="1"></fragment>
```

The `<fragment>` has to be in lower case, `<Fragment>` won't work too.

Your mixing some things up.

1) The `onCreate` method of the fragment has to inflate the whole layout of the fragment. After inflating the `Fragment` layout you can get the ListView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.id.searchlist, container, false);     
    markList = (ListView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.searchlist);
    markList.setAdapter(new OrderAdapter(MixView.mixContext.getBaseContext(), R.layout.searchinnerlistlayout, MixView.dataView.dataHandler.markerList));

    return contentView;
}
```

2) You did not define the id of the `ListView`, you defined its name. Change the layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/searchlist"></ListView> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I tried using that and now its failing on my fragment class when I try to inflate my listview.

Comment: Please add the code of your Fragment, its layout and the error log

Comment: I updated my code but its still failing here View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.id.searchlist, container, false);  and the log says the same thing about the resource not being found.

Comment: Which version of Android has your testing device/emulator? Fragments are available since honeycomb (Api level 11). Do you use the support package? (http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9026/discussion-between-herrmann-and-james-andresakis)

Comment: Yes Im using the support package via actionbarsherlock. Im testing on a motorola droid x2 running 2.3.4. I also test on a galaxy tab 10.1 running 3.2 .