# How can I show a different listview for each button pressed

Tags: android, listview, button, android-listview

I have a row of buttons that I want to populate a listview. That looks like this:

---

### Button1 | Button2 | Button3 | Button4

### List Item 1

### List Item 2

### List Item 3

If I press Button1, I will show one view and if I select Button2, I will show another view. I have the listview working with no button selected. However, I want to select a button and populate a listveiw based on the button selected. This is only my 2nd app so I may be going about it the wrong way.

Here is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    >
<VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >  
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/chapters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/chapters" /> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scales"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/scales" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_flat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/b_flat" /> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e_flat"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"    
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/e_flat" /> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/concert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/concert" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bass"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/bass" />  

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/video" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/practice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"    
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/practice" />                                                      
    </LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout 
          android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to select the "Chapters" button and populate the list button or select "concert" and populate the listview.

I don't know where or how to set the button pressed. Here is what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
     public class ChapterListFragment extends ListFragment {
private static final boolean VERBOSE = true;
private ArrayList<Chapters> mChapters;
private static final String TAG = "ChapterListFragment";

private Button mChaptersButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ onCreate +++");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_improvisation);
    mChaptersButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.chapters);
    mChaptersButton.setPressed(true);

    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.chapters_title);
    mChapters = ChapterList.get(getActivity()).getChapters();

    ChapterAdapter adapter = new ChapterAdapter(mChapters);
    setListAdapter(adapter);        

}
```

This didn't work because I can't use SetContentView in ListFragment. Also, the buttons didn't have focus. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you can use android tab layout to show the different lists/pages

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys What is the advantage of using android tab layout?

Comment: you can bind different listviews in your page as per your requirement.

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys Thanks, can you point me in the direction of any good examples?

Comment: Sure i will write a sample and provide you

Comment: Hi Please follow this tutorial . http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-vertical-tablayout_20.html

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys I looked at the tutorial. However, it would create a new page for each tab. What I want to do is select a list item and display an image based on the menu selection. I am attempting to use an options menu, but having trouble. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: you can show the same activity for that. else you can go for view flipper..

Answer (score 1):

create common listview adapter and populate the listview with different data set on each button click. Make sure to call your `adapter.clear()` so that the old data from listview will disappear. I hope you got the idea. For `setContentView, non of ListFragment and Fragment parent have the`setContentView()` method. You should have an Activity with a Layout and set your ListFragment there. rest check this link [Fragment setcontentView Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757751/android-listfragment-fails-on-setcontentview)

Comment: he can also use fragments and onClick of button replace the fragment using fragmentManager. In this way good thing is if he required same list anywhere else he can directly use it.