# The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type ShelfViewActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I'm new to Android programming and I have two errors that I cannot figure out I tried googling the issue and still no luck so my last resort is here like it should be! I'm creating Android launcher that has multiple tabs with swipe gestures to get from one fragment to the other all of my screens are working just fine except for the shelfviewactivity ( even though it says activity is a fragment)

These are the two errors I am getting into not understand how to fix:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type 
     ShelfViewActivity
    - The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type 
     ShelfViewActivity


error2:

The constructor ShelfViewActivity.VerticalAdapter(ShelfViewActivity, int, ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>>) is 
 undefined
```

Here is ShelfViewActivity:

```
package com.d4a.tobias;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShelfViewActivity extends ListFragment {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private VerticalAdapter verListAdapter;

    @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    }   

        /*
         * Calling Library & BookItem classes for create list of groups
         *  groupbyArrayBookItem return back array of array of items
         */
        Library lb = new Library();{
        for (BookItem item : BookItem.ALL_BOOKS) {
            lb.addBookItem(item);
        } //line 32
        ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>> groupList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>>();
        groupList = lb.groupbyArrayBookItem(Library.AUTHOR);

        verListAdapter = new VerticalAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.bookrow, groupList);
        setListAdapter(verListAdapter);

        verListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * This class add a list of ArrayList to ListView that it include multi
     * items as bookItem.
     */
    private class VerticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<BookItem>> {

        private int resource;

        public VerticalAdapter(Context _context, int _ResourceId,
                ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>> _items) {
            super(_context, _ResourceId, _items); //line 52
            this.resource = _ResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                rowView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resource,
                        null);
            } else {
                rowView = convertView;
            }

            HorizontalListView hListView = (HorizontalListView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.subListview);
            HorizontalAdapter horListAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(
                    getContext(), R.layout.item, getItem(position));
            hListView.setAdapter(horListAdapter);

            return rowView;
        }
    }

    /*
     * This class add some items to Horizontal ListView this ListView include
     * several bookItem.
     */
    private class HorizontalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookItem> {

        private int resource;

        public HorizontalAdapter(Context _context, int _textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<BookItem> _items) {
            super(_context, _textViewResourceId, _items);
            this.resource = _textViewResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View retval = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    this.resource, null);

            TextView topText = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView bottomText = (TextView) retval
                    .findViewById(R.id.author);

            topText.setText(getItem(position).getAuthor());
            bottomText.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());

            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: app now launches but i get a crash on Shelf View Activity

heres the logcat:

```
    11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305): Process: com.d4a.tobias, PID: 23305
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at com.d4a.tobias.ShelfViewActivity$VerticalAdapter.<init>(ShelfViewActivity.java:52)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at com.d4a.tobias.ShelfViewActivity.<init>(ShelfViewActivity.java:36)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at it.gmariotti.android.examples.googleaccount.MainFrag$MyAdapter.getItem(MainFrag.java:80)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:95)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:649)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:783)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1280)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:1176)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13315)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13372)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13268)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13372)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13268)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13372)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13268)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13372)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13268)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13372)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2379)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2251)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1881)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-11 17:17:44.500: E/AndroidRuntime(23305):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 17:17:51.318: E/ACDB-LOADER(177): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -8
```

Any links or references to show me what I'm doing wrong would be  fantastic

Thanks 1,000,000 times in advance

Answer (score 2):

`ListFragment` extends `Fragment` not `Activity`. You don't want to call `setContentView` in fragments. You should return a View from `onCreateView`.

Check following questions:

[How to setContentView in a fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108370/how-to-setcontentview-in-a-fragment)

[Android - ListFragment fails on setContentView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757751/android-listfragment-fails-on-setcontentview)

Comment: thanks that took care of error 1 this is the new error i'm getting :  The constructor ShelfViewActivity.VerticalAdapter(ShelfViewActivity, int, ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>>) is 
 undefined

Comment: @user2977501 For the second problem have you tried passing `getActivity()` instead of `this` ?

Comment: Thanks app now launches now but i get a crash on Shelf View Activity I added logcat to the post

Comment: what are line 36 and 52 in `ShelfViewActivity` ?

Comment: added line comments to the post